# Having trouble pushing to a branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

My github repository has a master branch and a development branch.

I created a local folder and used `git init`.

I then set the url of the origin remote by saying `git remote set-url <my repo's url>`

Now I added a file in my local folder to test a commit. After I added it I said this:

`git add .`

`git commit -m 'test commit'`

`git push origin development`

But then I got an error that said...

> `error: src refspec development does not match any.
>   error: failed to push some refs to '<my git url>'`

How can I just add files to a specific branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your branch called `development`? If you want to push your current `HEAD` to a new remote branch called development, try `git push origin HEAD:development`.